# Tridion Broker: get keyword id from item_categories_and_keywords using API

Tags: tridion-2011, broker

We have a component with a certain keyword field, which is located at the metadata tab.

Using the Broker API we would like retrieve the keyword for a certain component. 
The custom_meta is returning the keyword title. We can't use the taxonomy api to get the keyword object based on the keyword title.
If we use the API for querying the item_categories_and_keywords table, the API is only returning the ITEM_REFERENCE_ID. We don't need this ID, because this is the ID of the component which we already have.

So my question: is there a way to use the broker.querying API to get the result rows, instead of getting a list with string values containing the item_reference_id?

In the API there is information about query.getQueryResult() but the method is protected, so we can't use it.

Comment: You may be better off asking this question in the Tridion Q&A site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com